# Apache refuses to write to a log file after I manually delete all of its contents

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Why does Apache refuse to write to log files (the `ErrorLog`/`CustomLog` ones) after I have manually deleted their contents?

It will not write to those log files again until after I restart Apache.

Why is this the case? How can I safely purge a log file without having to restart Apache?

I have Apache 2.2.14 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: How do you delete the contents ?

Comment: @Dom I just open it with vim, do "dG" (which deletes all of the contents), and then save with "!wq". The ownership/group/permissions are not changed.

Comment: @AtomicFault Prrrobably because that's *not how you're supposed to rotate Apache logs*.  You should be using something like `logrotate` which sends an appropriate reload/restart signal to Apache(See Pedro's answer below). Nickgrim covered the "why" behind your logs stopping -- Apache is still writing to the old inode (which is no longer connected to the filesystem anywhere you can get at it)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just did a brief test:

```
$ echo vim test > vimtest
$ ls -i vimtest
35149 vimtest
$ vim vimtest
<dG, :wq>
$ ls -i vimtest
35148 vimtest
```

Note that `vimtest` has a different inode-number after editing it, and is thus actually a different file (albeit with the same name as the old file).

So, when you edit the file with vim it deletes the old file, and creates a new one with the same name. The problem you're seeing is caused by Apache still writing to the old (deleted) file (you can check this with `lsof`).

If you really want to truncate a log file, consider `truncate -s 0 /path/to/file.log` (which seems to truncate in-place)

Comment: echo > /path/to/file.log also works

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend forcing the rotation of the *Apache2* log files with:

```
$ sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

If you look into `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`, you'll see that the `Apache2` configuration has to be reloaded after deleting its log file with:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

On Ubuntu you can alternatively do:

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```